# T SQL Top 10 list of NULL Columns from a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, null, information-schema

I'm using SQL Server 2014.  I have a table with multiple columns in.  Is it possible to dynamically list the top 10 columns within the table and the percent of the records in each column that is NULL?  I do not want to hard code each column name in.

So the result set would be like:

```
Column       Percent_Null
ABC           100
QWE           75
REW           65
TRW           50
```

I've started with the below, but how I do get this in a list?  Ultimately the results need to go into a table for reporting.

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = STUFF((

SELECT ', CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN ' + Quotename(C.COLUMN_NAME) + ' IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.00 
/@TotalCount AS INT) AS [' + C.COLUMN_NAME + ' NULL %]
'
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
            WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tblMYTable'
                AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
            ORDER BY C.ORDINAL_POSITION
            FOR XML PATH('')
                ,type
            ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')


            PRINT @SQL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blargh, this is ugly, but it appears to do what you're after:

```
DECLARE @Table sysname = N'icp_yyclient',
        @Schema sysname = N'dbo';

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

--First get a Count, which will be one column per column    
SET @SQL = N'WITH Counts AS(' + @CRLF +
           N'    SELECT ' + 
           STUFF((SELECT N',' + @CRLF +
                         N'           (COUNT(CASE WHEN ' + QUOTENAME(C.[name]) + N' IS NULL THEN 1 END) * 1.) / COUNT(*) AS ' + QUOTENAME(c.[name] + N'_PercNULL')
                  FROM sys.schemas s
                       JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
                       JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
                  WHERE s.name = @Schema
                    AND t.name = @Table
                  ORDER BY c.column_id
                  FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,14,N'') + @CRLF +
           N'    FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@Schema) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@Table) + N')' + @CRLF +
--Now that we have a COUNT of column, we need to unpivot the data
           N'SELECT TOP(10) V.*' + @CRLF +
           N'FROM Counts C' + @CRLF +
           N'     CROSS APPLY(VALUES' +
           STUFF((SELECT N',' + @CRLF +
                         N'                       (N' + QUOTENAME(C.[name],'''') + N', C.' + QUOTENAME(c.[name] + N'_PercNULL') + N')'
                  FROM sys.schemas s
                       JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
                       JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
                  WHERE s.name = @Schema
                    AND t.name = @Table
                  ORDER BY c.column_id
                  FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,26,N'') + N')V(ColumnName,ColumnPercNULL)' + @CRLF +
          N'ORDER BY V.ColumnPercNULL DESC;';

--Uncommon to see the "mess". I strongly suggest ensuring you have retain CR/LF on in SSMS
--SELECT @SQL; --PRINT is limited to 4,000 characters, so probably too small.

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

For a table I have, (called `Asset`) this creates the following statement:

```
WITH Counts AS(
    SELECT (COUNT(CASE WHEN [AssetID] IS NULL THEN 1 END) * 1.) / COUNT(*) AS [AssetID_PercNULL],
           (COUNT(CASE WHEN [AssetName] IS NULL THEN 1 END) * 1.) / COUNT(*) AS [AssetName_PercNULL],
           (COUNT(CASE WHEN [TypeID] IS NULL THEN 1 END) * 1.) / COUNT(*) AS [TypeID_PercNULL],
           (COUNT(CASE WHEN [SerialNumber] IS NULL THEN 1 END) * 1.) / COUNT(*) AS [SerialNumber_PercNULL],
           (COUNT(CASE WHEN [BarcodeNumber] IS NULL THEN 1 END) * 1.) / COUNT(*) AS [BarcodeNumber_PercNULL],
           (COUNT(CASE WHEN [Manufacturer] IS NULL THEN 1 END) * 1.) / COUNT(*) AS [Manufacturer_PercNULL],
           (COUNT(CASE WHEN [Model] IS NULL THEN 1 END) * 1.) / COUNT(*) AS [Model_PercNULL],
           (COUNT(CASE WHEN [LocationID] IS NULL THEN 1 END) * 1.) / COUNT(*) AS [LocationID_PercNULL],
           (COUNT(CASE WHEN [IPAddress] IS NULL THEN 1 END) * 1.) / COUNT(*) AS [IPAddress_PercNULL],
           (COUNT(CASE WHEN [PurchaseDate] IS NULL THEN 1 END) * 1.) / COUNT(*) AS [PurchaseDate_PercNULL],
           (COUNT(CASE WHEN [SetupDate] IS NULL THEN 1 END) * 1.) / COUNT(*) AS [SetupDate_PercNULL],
           (COUNT(CASE WHEN [DecommissionDate] IS NULL THEN 1 END) * 1.) / COUNT(*) AS [DecommissionDate_PercNULL],
           (COUNT(CASE WHEN [ReasonID] IS NULL THEN 1 END) * 1.) / COUNT(*) AS [ReasonID_PercNULL],
           (COUNT(CASE WHEN [DecommissionBy] IS NULL THEN 1 END) * 1.) / COUNT(*) AS [DecommissionBy_PercNULL],
           (COUNT(CASE WHEN [InvoiceID] IS NULL THEN 1 END) * 1.) / COUNT(*) AS [InvoiceID_PercNULL],
           (COUNT(CASE WHEN [IsVirtual] IS NULL THEN 1 END) * 1.) / COUNT(*) AS [IsVirtual_PercNULL],
           (COUNT(CASE WHEN [HostAssetID] IS NULL THEN 1 END) * 1.) / COUNT(*) AS [HostAssetID_PercNULL],
           (COUNT(CASE WHEN [DestroyDate] IS NULL THEN 1 END) * 1.) / COUNT(*) AS [DestroyDate_PercNULL],
           (COUNT(CASE WHEN [DestroyID] IS NULL THEN 1 END) * 1.) / COUNT(*) AS [DestroyID_PercNULL],
           (COUNT(CASE WHEN [DestroyedBy] IS NULL THEN 1 END) * 1.) / COUNT(*) AS [DestroyedBy_PercNULL],
           (COUNT(CASE WHEN [ValueExVAT] IS NULL THEN 1 END) * 1.) / COUNT(*) AS [ValueExVAT_PercNULL],
           (COUNT(CASE WHEN [VATValue] IS NULL THEN 1 END) * 1.) / COUNT(*) AS [VATValue_PercNULL],
           (COUNT(CASE WHEN [ValueIncVAT] IS NULL THEN 1 END) * 1.) / COUNT(*) AS [ValueIncVAT_PercNULL]
    FROM [app].[Asset])
SELECT TOP(10) V.*
FROM Counts C
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(N'AssetID', C.[AssetID_PercNULL]),
                       (N'AssetName', C.[AssetName_PercNULL]),
                       (N'TypeID', C.[TypeID_PercNULL]),
                       (N'SerialNumber', C.[SerialNumber_PercNULL]),
                       (N'BarcodeNumber', C.[BarcodeNumber_PercNULL]),
                       (N'Manufacturer', C.[Manufacturer_PercNULL]),
                       (N'Model', C.[Model_PercNULL]),
                       (N'LocationID', C.[LocationID_PercNULL]),
                       (N'IPAddress', C.[IPAddress_PercNULL]),
                       (N'PurchaseDate', C.[PurchaseDate_PercNULL]),
                       (N'SetupDate', C.[SetupDate_PercNULL]),
                       (N'DecommissionDate', C.[DecommissionDate_PercNULL]),
                       (N'ReasonID', C.[ReasonID_PercNULL]),
                       (N'DecommissionBy', C.[DecommissionBy_PercNULL]),
                       (N'InvoiceID', C.[InvoiceID_PercNULL]),
                       (N'IsVirtual', C.[IsVirtual_PercNULL]),
                       (N'HostAssetID', C.[HostAssetID_PercNULL]),
                       (N'DestroyDate', C.[DestroyDate_PercNULL]),
                       (N'DestroyID', C.[DestroyID_PercNULL]),
                       (N'DestroyedBy', C.[DestroyedBy_PercNULL]),
                       (N'ValueExVAT', C.[ValueExVAT_PercNULL]),
                       (N'VATValue', C.[VATValue_PercNULL]),
                       (N'ValueIncVAT', C.[ValueIncVAT_PercNULL]))V(ColumnName,ColumnPercNULL)
ORDER BY V.ColumnPercNULL DESC;
```

This should give you some insight into how it works out the result.

Comment: I was just working on something equally as ugly. Does exactly what it says on the tin though +1

Comment: @Larnu You're a scholar and a gentleman.  However, it returns the columns then in the Column_PercentNULL it just states 1.0 for each?

Comment: Then all the columns are completely full of `NULL` values, @Michael . `1.0 = 100%` (basic artithimetic ;) )

Comment: If you don't believe it, comment out/remove the `TOP (10)` in the dynamic SQL and you'll get every column in the table, @Michael .

Comment: An alternative to `(COUNT(CASE WHEN [ValueIncVAT] IS NULL THEN 1 END) * 1.)` is `( Sum( case when [ValueIncVAT] is NULL then 1. end ) )`. The sum will be `numeric`. Using `100.` instead of `1.` will result in percent rather than a fraction named `ValueIncVAT_PercNULL`.

Comment: True, @HABO , I use `COUNT` as more of a preference; especially when I'm counting something. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way, using unpivot:

```
DECLARE @SCHEMANAME NVARCHAR(100)   =   'dbo'
DECLARE @TABLENAME  NVARCHAR(100)   =   'your_table_name'

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL =   'SELECT TOP (10) * FROM (SELECT '+
                    STUFF   (
                                (
                                    SELECT ', CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN ' + Quotename(C.COLUMN_NAME) + ' IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100.00/COUNT(*) AS INT) AS ' + QUOTENAME(C.COLUMN_NAME, '"') + CHAR(13)
                                    FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
                                    WHERE   TABLE_NAME = @TABLENAME
                                            AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @SCHEMANAME
                                    ORDER BY C.ORDINAL_POSITION
                                    FOR XML PATH(''),type
                                ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),
                                1, 2, ''
                            )+' FROM '+QUOTENAME(@SCHEMANAME)+'.'+QUOTENAME(@TABLENAME)+') V1 UNPIVOT (NullsPerc FOR ColumnName IN ('+

                    STUFF   (
                                (
                                    SELECT  ', '+ Quotename(C.COLUMN_NAME,'"') + CHAR(13)
                                    FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
                                    WHERE   TABLE_NAME = @TABLENAME
                                            AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @SCHEMANAME
                                    ORDER BY C.ORDINAL_POSITION
                                    FOR XML PATH(''),type
                                ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),
                                1, 2, ''
                            )+
                ')) AS UPVT

                ORDER BY NULLSPERC DESC'

SELECT  @SQL
```